# Saving .xlsx file to disc, form http post request

Tags: r, rest, shiny, upload, xlsx

I have a Plumber rest api, where i have a post request, that sends an excel file

when i access the request object like this

this is the attributes i get:

```
formContents <- Rook::Multipart$parse(req)
formContents$upload
```

this is what i get

```
["app_x_browser.xlsx","/tmp/RtmpWOKV2O/Multipart1d3261d35443","application/octet-stream","Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"app_x_browser.xlsx\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream"]
```

how can i save this response on disc, from this json data?
is there anyway to extract the data and save it onto a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could try to send your xlsx file in raw format with something like this in your plummer file

```
xlsx <- "path/to/xlsxfile.xlsx"
readBin(xlsx, "raw", n=file.info(xlsx)$size)
```

then of course you will need to handle this with your api request

```
[your call to the api] > results.xlsx
```

hope this helps